# Center div within responsive image div issue

Tags: svg, flexbox, responsive-images

I am trying to center a div with Flexbox.

This is my markup:

```
<header class="container">
  <div class="bg-image">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .masthead-->
</header>
```

I have used the aspect ratio method to make the background image in bg-class to be responsive with `background-size: contain` , the image used has the height of 600px and width of 800px, giving me a apsect ration of 75% which I use as padding-top.

But using this method to achieve a responsive background image does not work when I try to center the h1 in my logo class with Flexbox.

This is my css:

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;


    //padding-top: 75%;
    background: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/92/4d/31/924d316f8791c2c7f167ad189950d172.jpg")
      no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Disabling padding-top centers the logo class, but does not achieve the responsive image I desire, as it creates space on the sides or the top and bottom depending on screen space.

Is there a way where I could achieve a responsive image without cropping it out as with `background-size: cover;` , I would still like to use `background-size: contain;` and also centering a div horizontally and vertically within the bg-image class. I am planing to have a svg logo in the logo class which I would like to have centered within the bg-image class.

I am grateful for all input.

Comment: In your css you have the styles for `.container` but there is no `.container`  in your HTML

Comment: sorry, my bad.. I have corrected that error